# Save Current Time And Date To Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have Add a button to my app . When i click the button the current time save to Sp. But i want to save this to my firebase database. How can i do this?

```
private void saveButtonClickTime() {
        sp1.edit().putLong("mTime1", System.currentTimeMillis()).apply();
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you check the firebase docs?

Comment: what is sp1? is this object of DatabaseReference or FirebaseFirestore

Comment: No i want to save Data , Month and Year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This One. It will work .

```
 private void saveButtonClickTime() {
            sp1.edit().putLong("mTime1", System.currentTimeMillis()).apply();
            DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            rootRef.child("time").setValue(sp1);
    }
```

Comment: Let me try . :D